# Synchronize OpenSSL PHP AES cypher mode(cbc,256,iv) with OpenSSL C realization?

Tags: php, c, aes

OpenSSL on php and c gives different encoded data. Why is different encoded result? 
How to correct synchronize php and c modes with CBC-256-ivec? Don't see any different in php mode and c mode.

(Each decryption returns correct incoming string)

1.Php simple code is:

```
$s = 'key12345';
$v = '1234567812345678';
$c="HEllo111111111111111111999999999911111111111111111111Hello";
$d=openssl_encrypt($c,'aes-256-cbc',$s,1,$v);// options OPENSSL_RAW_DATA=1
echo bin2hex($d);
```

**First encoded bytes in hex are: e1 a9 52 4f 78 2b a8 41 b4 fe 2d 49 8d**

2.C simple code is:

```
AES_KEY aeskey;
char *simplekey = "key12345";
int status = AES_set_encrypt_key((unsigned char*) simplekey, 256, &aeskey);
unsigned char ivec[] = "1234567812345678";
unsigned char messagein[] = "HEllo111111111111111111999999999911111111111111111111Hello";
unsigned char * msg_enc_out = (unsigned char *)malloc(80);
memset(msg_enc_out, 0, 80);

AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char *) messagein, msg_enc_out, sizeof(messagein), &aeskey, ivec, AES_ENCRYPT);

  printf("\nencrypted:\n");
    printf("lenght=%d\n", sizeof(msg_enc_out));    
    for(i=0;*(msg_enc_out+i)!=0x00;i++)
        printf("%X ",*(msg_enc_out+i));
```

**First encoded bytes in hex are: C4 E8 19 30 98 5A 52 6 C7 9F 49 6D DE**

3. Online AES tool http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/
   gives one more incomparable result.(How to set 256 bit mode?)

AES Calculator - http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc

Comment: Strange, but 32 byte key made all 3 results the same